# Kafka to store the message on single partition for a user?

Tags: apache-kafka, message-queue

I have a ecommerce like system which produces user events of different kind .

I need to store them in kafka for asynch data analysis. I want events for specific users goes to one queue partition so that consumers gets all messages
on one partition . This won't be dedicated queue for a user. Which means single partition can store the data for multiple customer. Not sure how
I can achieve it in kafka ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send messages of specific users to the same partition, you can use the `key=` parameter of producer's send method. You can set this parameter to a byte encoded value which must be unique.
For example, in Python:

```
producer.send("topic", json.dumps(msg).encode()), key=str(user_id).encode())
```

This will ensure that messages concerning a given user will be pushed into the same topic's partition.

Answer (score 1):

@zebra8844 answer is correct. The same key will always go to the same partition ***unless*** you increase the number of partitions in the future then this will not be the case. So just keep this in mind for future.